# Get Current Time of CalendarEntry of Google Calendar API

Tags: java

I was wondering, is there anyway to get the current time of a CalendarEntry, of Google Calendar API.

I try to use the following hack :

```
       try {
            if (calendarEntry.getSummary().getPlainText().equalsIgnoreCase("XXX"))
            {
                calendarEntry.setSummary(new PlainTextConstruct("YYY"));
            }
            else
            {
                calendarEntry.setSummary(new PlainTextConstruct("XXX"));
            }

            calendarEntry = calendarEntry.update();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ServiceException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        // According to documentation, getUpdated shall returned CalendarEntry last 
        // update time.
        // Hopefully by explicitly modify the state of calendar, 
        // getUpdated will return latest time. 
        // Unfortunately, I find out the result is not always up-to-date. It will 
        // return pass time still.
        System.out.println("Calendar Entry = " + calendarEntry.getUpdated());
```

Getting NTP time from public time server is another option. However, I found out this doesn't meet my requirement, as it is quite time wasting, to make an extra query to another time server, instead of directly retrieve the information from Google itself.

Comment: What do you mean by "current time"? A calendar entry doesn't have a "current time". Do you not trust the time on your local system?

Comment: I mean, time as published by http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi
I do not trust the time on user machine. The user machine time may be 2:05:00 GMT, but Google machine may be 2:00:00 GMT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps getting NTP time from public time server is the only option.